# can we change a background thread operation to main thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, background-thread

How can i perform a JSON parsing in background thread in *viewDidLoad* and move it to main thread when clicks on a button. Now i tried

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(parseData) withObject:nil];


-(void)parseData    {

    MSJsonParser *parser = [[MSJsonParser alloc]initWithParserType:kCountriesParsing];
    parser._parserSource = self;
    [parser requestParsingWithUrl:COUNTRIES_URL ];

}
```

But i dont know how to change this background process to main thread. please help me

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The part in that method you want to run on the main thread, just stick it inside this GCD block and it will run it on the main thread:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //put stuff here
});
```

Comment: not sure if i get what you mean by parse it in the background and click on a button to make it go to main thread though... sounds like you are trying to get a method to potentially run on 2 different threads..

Comment: Doesn't `dispatch_sync` block the thread that made the call while it executes the block?

Answer (score 0):

See NSObject (NSThreadPerformAdditions) in NSThread

```
 - (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait modes:(NSArray *)array;
 - (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait;
```